# Why is the content in the paragraph being displayed as link?

Tags: html, css

I did not place my paragraph `<p>` contents(the ones that I don't want as links atleast) within `<a>`  tags that use the `href` attribute but they're being displayed as links.
 
First pic: entire page viewed on a browser; 
2nd Pic: the content that i **don't** want as hyperlinks.
The html code below shows the content that is within my `<main>` element.

`

```
   <p>Welcome to Forward Fitness Club. Our mission is to help our clients meet their fitness <b>AND</b> nutrition goals.<br> </p>

    <h2>  FREE ONE-WEEK TRIAL MEMBERSHIP</h2>


       <a href="Contact Us.html">Call Us today to Get Started</a> <br>

          <h3>Fitness Club Hours</h3> <br>

     <p>
         <ul>
                <li> Monday-Thursday: 6:00am - 6:00pm</li>
                <li> Friday: 6:00am - 4:00pm</li>
                <li> Saturday: 8:00am - 6:00pm</li>
                <li> Sunday: Closed</li>
         </ul>

    </p>
```

`

[image: Entire page]

[image: Part that i don't want as hyperlinks]

Comment: Probably you forgot to close  an anchor tag (`</a>`) before your Welcome to Forward...

Comment: @noobprogrammer Yeap you're right . thanks! I've been trying to figure what was wrong for hours

Answer (score 1):

Your markup works fine.

```html
<p>Welcome to Forward Fitness Club. Our mission is to help our clients meet their fitness <b>AND</b> nutrition goals.<br> </p>

<h2> FREE ONE-WEEK TRIAL MEMBERSHIP</h2>


<a href="Contact Us.html">Call Us today to Get Started</a> <br>

<h3>Fitness Club Hours</h3> <br>

<p>
  <ul>
    <li> Monday-Thursday: 6:00am - 6:00pm</li>
    <li> Friday: 6:00am - 4:00pm</li>
    <li> Saturday: 8:00am - 6:00pm</li>
    <li> Sunday: Closed</li>
  </ul>

</p>
```